# How to launch an app from another app

Tags: android, android-activity, package, android-package-managers

in my app i have to launch another app, only if it is not yet launched.

To launch an app what i do is:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();        
Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("package.of.app.to.launch");
startActivity(intent);
```

My problem is that if app is already launched, it will bring the app to the front. How can i launch app only if is not present in active and launched apps? thanks!

Comment: Can you please again elaborate your question, this is very confusing right now.

Comment: @Anupam: Whats so confusing about it.!

Comment: The target app, is it your own? Can you edit it's Manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ActivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html) to get Currently running Applications and to get  recent task executed on Device as:

```
 ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
 List<RunningTaskInfo> recentTasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    for (int i = 0; i < recentTasks.size(); i++) 
    {
         // Here you can put your logic for executing new task         
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get a list of all *running* or active apps and then check if the App you want to start is in it.

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcInfo = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
for(int i = 0; i < runningProcInfo.size(); i++){
        if(runningProcInfo.get(i).processName.equals("package.of.app.to.launch")) {
            Log.i(TAG, "XXXX is running");
        } else  {
            // RUN THE CODE TO START THE ACTIVITY
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know whether an app is running or not, you should have a look at [getRunningTasks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks%28int%29)

Also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10284241/1626878) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can get that which activity is running

```
List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo > taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1); 
String currentActivity=taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
```

then check

```
if(currentActivity!=(your activity))
{
    **your intent**
}
else{
"app already running"
}
```

hope it helps.
thank you

Comment: you need to post full code... (i.e. `am` you used).